# PDFbox arabic textnot show retrieve from database mysql

Tags: java, mysql, pdfbox

I want to display PDF report in arabic which will be generated through mysql database. Here is my code:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String relativeWebPath = "/font/A_Nefel_Adeti.ttf";
    String absoluteDiskPath = getServletContext().getRealPath(relativeWebPath);
    File file = new File(absoluteDiskPath);
    
    System.out.print(file);
 ByteArrayOutputStream output=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
 PDDocument document=new PDDocument();
 PDFont font = PDTrueTypeFont.load(document, new File(absoluteDiskPath),new WinAnsiEncoding());
PDPage test=new PDPage();
document.addPage(test);
 PDPageContentStream content=new PDPageContentStream(document, test);
 
final String EXAMPLE = "نديم";

System.out.print(EXAMPLE);

try{
     con=DBUtility.getConnection();
     stmt=con.prepareStatement("select * from login");
     rs=stmt.executeQuery();
     while(rs.next()){
         
         userName=rs.getString("UserName");
         password=rs.getString("Password");
         
        content.beginText();
         content.newLineAtOffset(50, 680);
         content.setFont(font, 12);
         content.showText(rs.getString("UserName"));
        // System.out.print(rs.getString("Password"));
         content.endText();

     
     }
     
 }catch(SQLException ex){
     ex.printStackTrace();
 }
 
 content.close();
 document.close();
   response.setContentType("application/pdf;base64,BASE_64_ENCODED_PDF");
 
response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"TestReport.pdf\"");
response.getOutputStream().write(output.toByteArray());


}
```

It shows arabic text on console but the PDF gives this error:

> type Exception report
>
> message U+0646 is not available in this font's encoding: WinAnsiEncoding
>
> description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from >fulfilling this request.

**Exception**

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: U+0646 is not available in this font's encoding: WinAnsiEncoding
org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDTrueTypeFont.encode(PDTrueTypeFont.java:368)
org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDFont.encode(PDFont.java:286)
org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPageContentStream.showText(PDPageContentStream.java:411)
uae.org.TestReport.doGet(TestReport.java:93)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Answer (score 0):

If not already done, please update to 2.0. The javadoc has a note:

> Note: Simple fonts only support 256 characters. For Unicode support,
>   use PDType0Font.load(PDDocument, File) instead.

So do this:

```
PDFont font = PDType0Font.load(document, new File(absoluteDiskPath);
```

This doesn't work for 1.8 or earlier.

Comment: thanks its works. but it will show the single character not word from left to right i want right to left as arabic writing.i include icu4j-49_1.jar but its not working.

Comment: That's a different topic, I suggest you open a new question for that (I can't help, sadly), and remove the sql stuff, and add a tag like "rtl". Hopefully somebody else can help.